# Performance of Neo4j community edition

Tags: python, neo4j

I am executing a complex query in Neo4j to find the childs of label named 'A' at level D.
Graph model: A->B->C->D
I'm always getting the same result(7ms) whether I increase the nodes to 1 million or I increase the hierarchy or increase the parent child ratio.
My question is when I will see the deviation in results.
When the value is going to increase.

I tried increasing nodes and parent child ratio.
I was expecting increase in timings.

Comment: Show your query.

Comment: Match (a:A)-[:R1]->(b:B)-[:R2]->(c:C)-[:R3]->(d:D)
where ID(a)=5
return d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time for finding children at the nth level is linear, although in most scenarios practically constant.

However finding A in the first place can get slower with bigger datasets. When you add indices for A's identifying property, then the timing should grow to log n, otherwise a whole node scan might be required.

Btw Neo4j caches data internally, so testing after startup will increase timings as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Let's suppose I have 1000 nodes of A and I use the query mentioned below:
MATCH (a:A {name: 'A1'})
RETURN a 
Increasing the nodes to 1 million will degrade the performance of Neo4j.
But, I am still getting the same result.
How can I tackle this situation?

Comment: Restarting Neo4j after inserting all the data will show the actual drop in performance. Once you've run your query, the specific nodes are chached, and running the same query additional times will show faster results